# cups authinforequirement set domain

Tags: linux, cups, smb

I want to change the default value WORKGROUP when cups authinforequired is set to "domain,username,password".
Then the user has to enter his credentials in a popup windows when printing a document.
I just can't find where to change the value for "domain" so that the user doesn't have to enter domain\username for the authentication.

I Already tried to change the value under smb.conf where the usercreds should've been stored because of winbind authentication on the linux os.